# how to show countries who has same time in one list

Tags: php, arrays, oop, datetime

i have this code:

```
   public function parse_timezones_list($timezones = '') {
    global $lang, $core;
    if(!is_array($timezones) || is_empty($timezones)) {
        $timezones = array('UTC', 'Africa/Casablanca', 'Africa/Dakar', 'Africa/Abidjan', 'Europe/Paris', 'Africa/Lagos', 'Africa/Algiers', 'Africa/Tunis', 'Africa/Cairo', 'Asia/Beirut', 'Asia/Amman', 'Africa/Nairobi', 'Asia/Riyadh', 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Asia/Hong_Kong');
    }
    $gmttime = gmmktime(gmdate('H'), gmdate('i'), gmdate('s'), gmdate('n'), gmdate('d'), gmdate('Y'));
    $timezones_list.='<ul class="list-group">';
    foreach($timezones as $timezone) {
        $timezone_obj = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
        $time_obj = new DateTime('now', $timezone_obj);
        $timezone_city = str_replace('_', ' ', explode('/', $timezone));
        if(empty($timezone_city[1])) {
            $timezone_city[1] = $timezone_city[0];
        }
        $timezones_list .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.$lang->sprint($lang->timecity, date('H:i', $gmttime + $timezone_obj->getOffset($time_obj)), ucwords($timezone_city[1])).'</li>';
    }
    $timezones_list.='</ul>';
    return $timezones_list;
}
```

so the result is this :`14:45 UTC time
14:45 Casablanca time
14:45 Dakar time
14:45 Abidjan time
16:45 Paris time
15:45 Lagos time
15:45 Algiers time
15:45 Tunis time
16:45 Cairo time`

i want to show that for every country who has the same time in one line, here for example i want like that:`14:45 Casablanca time,Dakar time,Abidjan time`

thank u for your help

Comment: The same time when? Right now? Btw, it would be good to list your language in the tags - that will be more relevant than "arrays", "function" or "oop".

Comment: yes right now, i mean insted of showing every counry the time, i need t show everycountry who has the same time together @JonSkeet

Comment: Use an array to group them…?! `$timezones['14:45'][] = $timezone` (replace "14:45" dynamically of course).

Comment: can u write me the code please thank u @deceze

Comment: Just to note, in case that fits your use case: if you're asking a user to select their timezone (e.g. as a preference setting), grouping won't do. The timezones may be the same time *now*, but that'll diverge due to DST.

Comment: no the user cant choose his local time all i want is something like this: 14:45: dakar,abidjan casablanca @deceze

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% I understand the question, but this code will group locations into their respective time zones :

```
$timezones = array('Africa/Casablanca', 'Africa/Dakar', 'Africa/Abidjan', 'Europe/Paris', 'Africa/Lagos', 'Africa/Algiers', 'Africa/Tunis', 'Africa/Cairo', 'Asia/Beirut', 'Asia/Amman', 'Africa/Nairobi', 'Asia/Riyadh', 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Dubai', 'Asia/Hong_Kong');
$locations = array();
foreach ($timezones as $timezone) {
    $dateTime = new DateTime(); 
    $dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone)); 
    $locations[$dateTime->format('T')][] = $timezone;
}
```

It creates an array out of $locations that has a key for the timezone and values for the regions. Output is something like :

```
Array
(
    [WET] => Array
        (
            [0] => Africa/Casablanca
        )

    [GMT] => Array
        (
            [0] => Africa/Dakar
            [1] => Africa/Abidjan
        )

    [CEST] => Array
        (
            [0] => Europe/Paris
        )

    [WAT] => Array
        (
            [0] => Africa/Lagos
        )
)
```